# MDL "advanced" grid structure

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm trying to achieve something similar as the [mdl dashboard example](https://getmdl.io/templates/dashboard/) where you have one card on the left and two cards on the right in desktop view (like first image in the imgur album),
and when it changes to tablet layout then it becomes like the second image in the imgur album:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqpHG.jpg

The reason it works in the example is because img-C only has a width of 3 in tablet layout because there's a hidden 1-col separator to make up for the missing space caused by mdl-grid--no-spacing.

My question is, how could this layout structure be achieved if I wanted both img-B and img-C to have a 4-col width in tablet layout?

Comment: Do you mean you want the 3 cards layout on tablet view to look the same as desktop view, ie. card-A on left-hand side, card-B and card-C on right-hand side?

Comment: No, on tablet view I'd like card-A to have its own col and card-B and card-C to share a col
  
I managed to get something running doing some dirty fix like below, but I think there must be a better way (also heard should avoid '!important' at all cost
  
`@media (max-width: 839px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  .card-width-fix {
    width: calc(50% - 8px) !important;
  }
}`

Comment: I'm still unclear about what you aim for. Please see: http://imgur.com/a/UwnKo . Are you trying to make the layout looks like the first image or the second image?

Comment: both :).. in desktop view it should look like the first image, and in tablet view it should look like the second image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely avoid `!important` when you design a theme but I see nothing wrong with using it if you are overriding `mdl class` layout. See: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Let simplify the MDL example layout to:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop" />
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop" />
    <div class="mdl-cell demo-separator mdl-cell--1-col" />
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--3-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop" />
  </div>
</div>
```

To achieve your desired look, hide the `.demo-separator` in tablet view and set the 3rd card class to 4-column-tablet instead of 3:

```
<div class="mdl-cell demo-separator mdl-cell--1-col mdl-cell--hide-tablet" />
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop" />
```

You will need then need to readjust the size of the columns in the 2nd row. I would add an override class on the `.mdl-grid--no-spacing`(let's call it `.grid-central--spacing`):

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing grid-central--spacing">
```

In my `style.css`, I can override the styling as:

```
@media (max-width: 839px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  .grid-central--spacing .mdl-cell--4-col-tablet {
     width: calc(50% - 8px) !important;
  }
  .grid-central--spacing .mdl-cell--4-col-tablet:first-child {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }
  .grid-central--spacing .mdl-cell--4-col-tablet:last-child {
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
}
```

There should be a `16px` spacing between the 2 cards in tablet view now.

Comment: By the way, I learned a lot from your answer and solution (which was much better than mine), and good to know I don't need to worry about !important :).. 
mdl-cell--hide-x will definitely come in handy in the future as well.. thanks again :)